# Putting BigDecimal data into HSQLDB test database using DbUnit

Tags: hibernate, testing, hsqldb, dbunit

I'm using Hibernate JPA in my backend. I am writing a unit test using JUnit and DBUnit to insert a set of data into an in-memory HSQL database.

My dataset contains:

```
<order_line order_line_id="1" quantity="2" discount_price="0.3"/>
```

Which maps to an OrderLine Java object where the discount_price column is defined as:

```
@Column(name = "discount_price", precision = 12, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal discountPrice;
```

However, when I run my test case and assert that the discount price returned equals 0.3, the assertion fails and says that the stored value is 0. If I change the discount_price in the dataset to be 0.9, it rounds up to 1.

I've checked to make sure HSQLDB isn't doing the rounding and it definitely isn't because I can insert an order line object using Java code with a value like 5.3 and it works fine.

To me, it seems like DBUtils is for some reason rounding the number I've defined. Is there a way I can force this to not happen? Can anyone explain why it might be doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this question since I was fighting with a similar problem, unfortunately in my current setup I'm not able to upgrade hibernate.  So I found a different solution which fixes the problem without the need to upgrade hibernate.  Thought it would not harm to share.  You simply extend the HSQLDialect

```
public class HSQLNumericWithPrecisionDialect extends HSQLDialect {
    public HSQLNumericWithPrecisionDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType( Types.NUMERIC, "numeric($p, $s)" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using the latest version of hibernate as well as hsqldb, so hibernate upgrade was not an option for me. I used this approach and replace $p with 5 and $s by 2(precision and scale) and it worked like a charm. Thanks @krico

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem...fixed by upgrading to to Hibernate 3.6

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick test on my side with DbUnit 2.2.2, HSQLDB 1.8.0.10 and Hibernate EM 3.4.0.GA and things are working as expected:

- DbUnit correctly inserts decimal values into a `discount_price` column of type `numeric(12,2)`
- Hibernate correctly reads the `discount_price` values into a `BigDecimal discountPrice`
- the following `assertEquals(0.3d, orderLine.getDiscountPrice().doubleValue())` passes

So my questions are:

- What version of DbUnit do you use exactly?
- How do you do your assert exactly? Do you DbUnit API for that too?